# Webnovel(?) About Man Waking Up In Future Utopia On Mars

Tags: story-identification

I can recall reading an excerpt of the first chapter of this work. I believe the rest was hidden by a paywall, even though the story was primarily online. It was about a police officer (or maybe a fireman?) responding to a call. He's suddenly shot by a psychotic ex-military sniper who decided to not take his medicine (unrelated to call). He awakens in the future in a utopia after being cryogenically frozen. I would have read it sometime in the past 10 years, but likely after 2010. I also believe it took place on a terraformed Mars less than a thousand years into the future.

Comment: Any particular sites you used to read webnovels on?

Comment: No... I think it was a site just for that work. I remember being surprised that there was only an excerpt. I believe it was a dedicated website for that author's work.